# tag-based site statistics

Tags: support

I want to analyze the kinds of topics that appear in SQA questions.  Questions are tagged, and you can determine how many questions are associated with each tag.  I would like to know, for example, how many questions are in the union of selenium and selenium2, or going further, which test-automation questions are neither selenium nor selenium2.  Is there a tool for that?

There aren't that many questions on SQA.  I know I could write something to grab the data question-by-question from the site, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a union of them by searching for both tags, for example `[selenium] [selenium2]` will match questions that have both [selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium) and [selenium2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium2).

You can negate terms to remove them from the search. For example, `[selenium] -[selenium2]` yields all [selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium) that do not have [selenium2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium2).

Most questions have neither of these, but `-[selenium] -[selenium2]` is considered to have "no positive criteria" for searching. The system assumes that each tag contains only a small subset of the entire site, so it would not be reasonable from a "search" perspective to allow a result set to include almost the entire site, even though you're just looking for the count.

Comment: Thank you, @corsiKa.  Just to make sure I understand, does `[selenium] [selenium2]` match questions that have *both* tags or *either* tag?  Of course, matching both tags would constitute an *intersection* rather than a *union*.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I can calculate the union by querying the two separately, adding the results, and then subtracting the intersection.

Comment: That matches BOTH. I don't know exactly how to match either.

Comment: As it turns out, there is a way to match either; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags.  The search box does not support it, but the URL does.  For example, http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium%20or%20selenium2 matches the union of `selenium` and `selenium2`.

Comment: How'd you figure that out? You'd have to think like a tester to... oh, oh I see.